# Match string that contains two "needles"

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, pcre

I have a string that looks a little like this

```
1: u:mads g:folk 2: g:andre u:jens u:joren
```

what I need is a way (I'm guessing by regex) to get for instance u:jens and the number (1 or 2) it is after.

how do I go about this in php (preferably with just one function)?

Comment: What is the search string?

Comment: that's pretty much my question summed up

Comment: No you want the *pattern*, I want to know what you are looking for.

Comment: In other words: Why `u:jens` and not `u:joren` or `g:andre`

Comment: ah, no reason really, the search string could be anyone of those (or multyply of them)

Comment: So your input is the "name"? Why do you need to return the name if it's your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find all matches. If you only need the first, use `preg_match` instead.

```
<?php
$subject = '1: u:mads g:folk 2: g:andre u:jens u:joren 3: u:jens';
preg_match_all('#(\d+):[^\d]*?u:jens#msi', $subject, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    var_dump($match);
}
?>
```

Comment: A side note: it would fail if a digit may be a valid character of a string

Comment: I'm making the assumption it isn't a valid character since the sample doesn't contain it, but that's very true - know the assumptions you're making or you'll be constantly fixing up your regex.

Comment: Yep, I didn't want to mention your solution is wrong, just made a note for the people who don't understand regexes well.

Comment: Also note that `[^\d]` will fail faster than `.*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(\d+):(?!.*\d+:.*).*u:jens
```

Where the digit you're looking for is put in the first capturing group. So, if you're using PHP:

```
$matches = array();
$search = '1: u:mads g:folk 2: g:andre u:jens u:joren';
if (preg_match('/(\d+):(?!.*\d+:.*).*u:jens/', $search, $matches)) {
  echo 'Found at '.$matches[1]; // Will output "Found at 2"
}
```

Comment: What if you try searching `u:mads`?

Comment: Good point: This regex will only match the digit if the key (e.g., `u:jens`) appears in the last digit group.

Answer (score 0):

This will parse the string and return an array containing the number keys in which the search string was found:

```
function whereKey($search, $key) {
  $output = array();
  preg_match_all('/\d+:[^\d]+/', $search, $matches);

  if ($matches[0]) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $k) {
      if (strpos($k, $key) !== FALSE) {
        $output[] = (int) current(split(':', $k));
      }
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

For example:

```
whereKey('1: u:mads g:folk 2: g:andre u:jens u:joren', 'u:jens')
```

...will return:

```
array(1) { [0]=> int(2) }
```